# Display content on transparent image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display html elements (forms, text, etc) on an image, which has been made transparent with gimp. But whatever I tried, the content is hidden by the image.

I've changed the page's background color just to be sure the browser wasn't changing the transparent part to white for some reason, and it does not.

I also have tried to play with the z-index property but this didn't work.

On reloading the page, I can see the text displaying correctly, but then the image displays and overlays it.

```css
#foo{
  position: relative;
}

#foo img{
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

#bar{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id='foo'>
   <img src='my_img' />
   <div id='bar'>
   <!--This is where I want to write what will be displayed on the transparent image.-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I didnt find any similar situations, neither here neither on other websites so any suggestion is welcomed.

Edit: Actually I set the top and left CSS properties and it's now working fine.

Comment: The id ='bar' div's id property isn't terminated properly. This code seemed to work properly once that was fixed.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this a typing mistake that is not in the code, ill check when I’ll get back home. Thank you

Comment: Just checked, it's written correctly

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered background-image?

```
#bar {
  background-image: url('/path/to/myimg.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: What if you use `#foo` as the selector?